# How to use the certificates CA Certificate, Client Certificate, Client Key while sending a secure SSL/TLS request in a flutter mobile app

Tags: flutter, dart, request, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

Docker Engine provides encrypted API(works on HTTPS (SSL/TLS)) that requires:

1. ca.pem (CA Certificate)
2. cert.pem (Client  Certificate  )
3. key.pem (Client Key)
   while sending an API request.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/protect-access/

In python, I am able to pass these certificates using the requests method to send a request to the server (Client-side):

```html
import requests

CA_CERT = './ssl-tls-keys/ca.pem'

CLIENT_CERT = './ssl-tls-keys/cert.pem'
CLIENT_KEY = './ssl-tls-keys/key.pem'

URL = 'https://65.0.95.227:2376/containers/json?all=1'


def get_container_list():
    response = requests.get(url=URL, cert=(CLIENT_CERT, CLIENT_KEY),
                            verify=CA_CERT)
    return response.json()


def print_containers_data():
    for container in get_container_list():
        print('Container [Id: %s, Name: %s, Status: %s]' %
              (container['Id'], container['Names'][0], container['Status']))


print_containers_data()
```

Using curl, We can send the request using:

```html
curl https://$HOST:2376/images/json \
  --cert cert.pem \
  --key key.pem \
  --cacert ca.pem
```

I am not able to figure out how can I use these 3 certificates while sending the https request to the Docker Engine API in flutter.

I tried using HTTP and DIO packages but didn't find anything there.